# unable to read csv file saved with encoding "UTF-8-SIG"

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding

I got data that I crawled using Scrapy, which saves as csv file with encoding `utf-8-sig`. The data has many different special characters: Korean, Russian, Chinese, Spanish,..., a star symbol (★), and this , and this ...

So Scrapy can save, and I can view those on Notepad++ or app like CSVFileView. But when I load in R using `mydata <- read.csv(<path_to_file>, fileEncoding="UTF-8-SIG", header=FALSE)`, I got this error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt", encoding = fileEncoding) : 
  unsupported conversion from 'UTF-8-SIG' to ''
```

If I don't specify the encoding, I can load but the symbols will become characters like `â˜` and the first column head will be appended with `ï..`

Which encoding should I choose to include all characters?

Comment: @H1 yes I did, it stops loading when it encounters such special character

Comment: Perhaps try `read.csv(<path_to_file>, encoding="UTF-8", header=FALSE)` - note that this is using the `encoding` argument not the `fileEncoding` argument.

Comment: @H1 yes that works! But then my first column head is appended with `X.U.FEFF.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the input is already encoded as `UTF-8`, you should use the `encoding` argument to read the file as-is. Using `fileEncoding` will attempt to re-encode the file.

```
mydata <- read.csv(<path_to_file>, encoding="UTF-8", header=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I prevent `X.U.FEFF.` from being appended to my  first column's header?

Comment: It's being caused by a byte order mark (BOM) so using the `fileEncoding` option `UTF-8-BOM` should deal with this, however as you said this didn't work, perhaps you can try `readr::read_csv()` instead.  Or, as a last resort, you could rename the first column.